# Unresolved dependency even after adding `<repository>` tag in pom.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create an intellij-based plugin using maven build system. I found that actual API for creating plugins is in package `com.jetbrains.intellij.idea.ideaIC`. I've searched for this package on https://mvnrepository.com (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/2022.1)
I've added a repository in my `pom.xml`

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>intellij</id>
        <name>Intellij Repository</name>
        <url>https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and needed dependency as

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jetbrains.intellij.idea</groupId>
        <artifactId>ideaIC</artifactId>
        <version>2022.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After I press `Reload All Maven Projects` in Intellij IDEA it says

> Unresolved dependency: 'com.jetbrains.intellij.idea:ideaIC:jar:2022.1'

What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: Why do you need Maven? According to https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-started.html it is easier to use Gradle

Comment: @konstantinannikov Maven has a simple xml structure with known schema. Gradle has unknown structure with weird syntax (IMO, forgive me gradle users)

Answer (score 1):

- First make sure the dependency with the specified version exists.
- If it exists go to File and click Invalidate cache make sure to check clear file system and mark downloaded.. then click Invalidate and Restart button this will restart intellij.
- After Intellij restared right click on pom.xml -> maven-> download sources. This will download all the necessary dependency.
- Then reload all maven projects.